# Read-only connection to a slave instance using monger

Tags: mongodb, clojure, monger

I have a replica set and I want to establish standalone read-only connection to a slave instance.

Normally, I should experience no problems doing it. The only thing I ought to do is to set `slaveOk=true` to be able to query it with read operations. It works great when I'm using `nodejs` or mongo console, but I found no way to do it using `monger`.

The strangest thing is that I'm getting an exception when I'm calling `set-db!` function:

> MongoException not talking to master and retries used up 
>   com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.innerCall (DBTCPConnector.java:314)

Establishing [replica-set connection](http://clojuremongodb.info/articles/connecting.html#connecting_to_a_replica_set) is not an option for me.

Currently I'm using `[com.novemberain/monger "1.4.0"]`.

Thanks!

---

**Update:** I looked through [Java MongoDB Driver API Documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/Mongo.html) and found [`slaveOk`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/Mongo.html#slaveOk()) method. I wrote the following code, hoping it'll work:

```clj
(defn slave-connect!
  [& args]
  (mg/set-connection!
    (doto (apply mg/connect args)
          (.slaveOk))))
```

But all I've got is a new exception:

> MongoException not master  com.mongodb.CommandResult.getException
>   (CommandResult.java:100)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I solved my problem using [com.mongodb.DBApiLayer Documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DBApiLayer.html).

So, the right solution is to set [ReadPreference](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/ReadPreference.html) to [secondary](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/ReadPreference.html#secondary()) using [setReadPreference](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DB.html#setReadPreference(com.mongodb.ReadPreference)) method and then to make the database read-only using [setReadOnly()](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DB.html#setReadOnly(java.lang.Boolean)) method:

```clj
(import 'com.mongodb.ReadPreference)

(defn use-slave-db!
  [& args]
  (mg/set-db!
    (doto (apply mg/get-db args)
          (.setReadOnly true)
          (.setReadPreference
            (ReadPreference/secondary)))))
```

Now whe are able to connect to a slave instance using `use-slave-db!` function instead of default [`use-db!`](http://reference.clojuremongodb.info/monger.core.html#var-use-db%21) macro.

Answer (score 2):

I found the following works too under monger 2.0.0:

```
(connect-via-uri "mongodb://host/db?readOnly=true&readPreference=secondary")
```

Comment: Good catch! Though, using Connection String doesn't seem like a proper way of implementing this functionality.

Comment: Where did you know about "readOnly" parameter in connection string? It's not listed in [the manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/), so I doubt it has any impact here.